# Swift protocol syntax

Tags: swift, syntax, protocols

I see this syntax in Swift

```
protocol myProtocol : class {
some functions
}
```

I didn't see this in the documentation - what is the `:class` part and how/when should it be used?

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_class_protocol

Comment: It defines a class only protocol. `: class` keyword means that the protocol can only be adopted by class types.